# How to Customize the navigation bar for QLPreviewcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I want to customize the navigation bar of QLPreviewcontroller but instead of many solutions for this none of them worked for me. If I am sub-classing the QLPreviewcontroller then I am not able to set its data source to current controller and even not able to push it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What part are you wanting/trying to customize?  What do you mean by "I am not able to set its data source to current controller and even not able to push it: i've used `QLPreviewController`, I made a custom VC that subclassed `QLPreviewController` that I added as a childVC using, `.didMove(toParentViewController:)`

Comment: when i am trying to push this controller through self.navigationController.pushViewcontroller then it gets crashed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS